# specify java process properties for GC when initiating process from .NET application

Tags: java, .net

I have a Java application which starts up via a .NET application.  What would be the best approach to use in order to control JVM heap size parameters etc. in this case.  I would like to avoid using a bat file from where to run the Java process.

Comment: How are you starting it now? Are you asking how to start a process in .NET with arguments or which arguments to pass to `java`?

Comment: thanks for responding - right now, the C# app is using the executable jar file to kickstart the process.